# Python - How do you loop through a dictionary to check the values for certain text?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension, key-value

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'https://www.youtube.com/sw.js_data': ['HTTP/2 200 OK',
  'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff',
  'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
  'Pragma: no-cache',
  'Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
  'Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 17:59:34 GMT',
  'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="response.bin"; filename*=UTF-8\'\'response.bin',
  'Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000',
  'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN',
  'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy-Report-Only: same-origin; report-to="ATmXEA_XZXH6CdbrmjUzyTbVgxu22C8KYH7NsxKbRt94"',
  'Permissions-Policy: ch-ua-arch=*, ch-ua-bitness=*, ch-ua-full-version=*, ch-ua-full-version-list=*, ch-ua-model=*, ch-ua-platform=*, ch-ua-platform-version=*',
  'Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version',
  'Server: ESF',
  'X-Xss-Protection: 0',
  'Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"'],
 'https://www.google.com/client_204?&atyp=i&biw=1440&bih=849&dpr=1.5&ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ': ['HTTP/2 204 No Content',
  'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000',
  "Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1",
  'Bfcache-Opt-In: unload',
  'Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 17:59:10 GMT',
  'Server: gws',
  'Content-Length: 0',
  'X-Xss-Protection: 0',
  'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN',
  'Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2022-03-14-17; expires=Wed, 13-Apr-2022 17:59:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; SameSite=none',
  'Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"']}
```

I am having a terribly difficult time trying to call and search these keys and values within this dictionary. I am attempting to write a for loop or list comprehension that will search through each value in the dictionary and look for a certain text ("Strict-Transport-Security", for example). After looping through, I would like for it to print the key and then the result of the search. So example desired output for this dictionary would be:

```
https://www.youtube.com/sw.js_data: Strict-Transport-Security missing
https://www.google.com/client_204?&atyp=i&biw=1440&bih=849&dpr=1.5&ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ: Strict-Transport-Security present
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Assuming it is possible to do but I am having difficulty getting to that point. Thank you!

Comment: Why not use a dictionary for the header fields, instead of a list of strings?

Comment: `any(s.startswith("Strict-Transport-Security:" for s in headers)` will tell you if the header appears in the list `headers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header = 'Strict-Transport-Security'

for url in mydictionary:
    if any(s.startswith(header) for s in mydictionary[url]):
        print(f"{header} found for {url}")
    else:
        print(f"{header} missing for {url}")
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you! Would it be a drastic change to have this check for multiple header values? Would think the any logic would have to change

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share with you another approach - you could convert your list of strings into dictionary

```
def parse_list(list_of_str):
    res = {}
    for element in list_of_str:
        try:
            x = element.split(":")
            res[x[0]] = x[1].strip()
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return res

parsed = {url: parse_list(l) for url, l in your_dict.items()}
```

Now you can use it as normal dictionary:

```
for url, subdict in parsed.items():
    print(url, "present" if "Strict-Transport-Security" in subdict else "missing")
```

Comment: I like the alternative approach! Thank you I may have to come back and use this approach